# php search and replace first element in div

Tags: php, search, html, replace

i have a structure that looks like this

```
<div class="table">
  <div> <p> name1 </p> <p> title1 </p> </div>
  <div> <p> name2 </p> <p> title2 </p> </div>
  <div> <p> name3 </p> <p> title3 </p> </div>
</div>
```

and it continues a few hundred more times. what can i write in php that will search ( class="table" > div ) and add a class to only the first 'p' in each 'div'?

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = '<div class="table">
  <div> <p class="first"> name1 </p> <p> title1 </p> </div>
  <div> <p> name2 </p> <p> title2 </p> </div>
  <div> <p> name3 </p> <p> title3 </p> </div>
</div> ';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class="table"]/div/p[position()=1]');

$addClass = 'first';

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->hasAttribute('class')) {
        $classes = preg_split('/\s+/', $node->getAttribute('class'));
        if (in_array($addClass, $classes)) {
            continue;
        }
    } else {
        $classes = array();
    }
    $classes[] = $addClass;
    $node->setAttribute('class', implode(' ', $classes));
}

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

Updated to not add `first` twice :)

#### Output

```
string(340) "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
<html><body><div class="table"> 
  <div> <p class="first"> name1 </p> <p> title1 </p> </div> 
  <div> <p class="first"> name2 </p> <p> title2 </p> </div> 
  <div> <p class="first"> name3 </p> <p> title3 </p> </div> 
</div></body></html> 
"
```

You may have noticed DOMDocument *helpfully* adds the HTML wrapper tags (`html`, `body`, etc) in for you.

You can get the `body` element's inner HTML like so...

```
$output = '';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
       $output .= $dom->saveXML($node);
}
```

#### Output

```
<div class="table"> 
  <div> <p class="first"> name1 </p> <p> title1 </p> </div> 
  <div> <p class="first"> name2 </p> <p> title2 </p> </div> 
  <div> <p class="first"> name3 </p> <p> title3 </p> </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: The Code is clean but the OP was asking for a PHP solution not js.  While the JS works great, in some cases it is not a good idea in case web users might not have js enabled.

Comment: @TJSherrill Please demonstrate where I have used JavaScript in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP DOMDocument to traverse it and add attributes:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

Cleaner way than string search.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `phpQuery`: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

You can walk through DOM object like with `jQuery`:

```
phpQuery::newDocument($htmlCode)->find('div.table div')->find('p:first').attr('class', 'myVal');;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider doing this in javascript?  You will  find it much easier using something like [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Could wreck his layout with JavaScript disabled though.